# Avoid using for loop. Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of shape (3,2):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0.,0.],[0.25,-0.125],[0.5,-0.125]])
```

I was trying to build a matrix (***matrix***) of dimensions (6,2), with the results of the outer product of the elements i,i  of arr and arr.T. At the moment I am using a for loop such as:

```
size = np.shape(arr)
matrix = np.zeros((size[0]*size[1],size[1]))
for i in range(np.shape(arr)[0]):
    prod = np.outer(arr[i],arr[i].T)
    matrix[size[1]*i:size[1]+size[1]*i,:] = prod
```

Resulting:

```
matrix =array([[ 0.      ,  0.      ],
               [ 0.      ,  0.      ],
               [ 0.0625  , -0.03125 ],
               [-0.03125 ,  0.015625],
               [ 0.25    , -0.0625  ],
               [-0.0625  ,  0.015625]])
```

Is there any way to build this ***matrix*** without using a for loop (e.g. broadcasting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend arrays to `3D` with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#structural-indexing-tools) keeping the first axis aligned, while letting the second axis getting pair-wise multiplied, perform multiplication leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and reshape to `2D` -

```
matrix = (arr[:,None,:]*arr[:,:,None]).reshape(-1,arr.shape[1])
```

---

We can also use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
matrix = np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',arr,arr).reshape(-1,arr.shape[1])
```

`einsum` string representation might be more intuitive as it lets us visualize three things :

- Axes that are aligned (axis=0 here).
- Axes that are getting summed up (none here).
- Axes that are kept i.e. element-wise multiplied (axis=1 here).